# Decrease the number of stages by making them into jobs

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines-yaml

I tried to create the below yaml pipeline config file. Can I get some help on reducing the number of stages in YAML pipeline. This is to reduce number of stages per domain.

```
name: '$(Date:yyyy.MM.dd)$(Rev:.rr)'

trigger: 
  branches:
    include:
    - master
    - features/*

pool:
  name: CustomPool

stages:

  - template: templates\build.yaml  

  - template: templates\deploy.yaml  
    parameters:      
      Environment:  'dev'
      IsEnabled: true 
      Domain: 'domainX'
      ServerList:
      - name:       ServerX
        restartIIS: true

  - template: templates\deploy.yaml  
    parameters:      
      Environment:  'test'
      IsEnabled: true 
      Domain: 'domainY'
      ServerList:
      - name:       ServerY
        restartIIS: false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scenario 1: If you don't want to use stages, you can only use jobs in the main YAML and your template.  There is a demo you can refer to.

azure-pipelines.yml

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

jobs:
  - template: JobTemplate1.yml
  - template: JobTemplate2.yml
  - template: JobTemplate3.yml
```

JobTemplate1.yml

```
jobs:
  - job: job1_1
    steps:
    - script: echo This is job1_1
  - job: job1_2
    steps:
    - script: echo This is job1_2
```

In this example, each template has 2 jobs. Eventually you can see a total of 6 jobs running.
[image]

Scenario 2: If you want to use stages in your main YAML but just want to decrease the stages in your template, you can use only one stage and several jobs in your template.

azure-pipelines.yml

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

stages:
  - template: template1.yml
  - template: template2.yml
  - template: template3.yml
```

template1.yml

```
stages:
- stage: Template1_Stage
  jobs:
  - job: Template1_Stage_job1
    steps:
    - script: echo This is Template1_Stage_job1
  - job: Template1_Stage_job2
    steps:
    - script: echo This is Template1_Stage_job2
```

In this example, template1 has one stage and two jobs. Template2 has two stages, and each stage has one job. Template3 has one stage and one job. For your case, you can refer to template1.

[image]